# QGIS Python ignore invalid geometries

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-processing

In QGIS 3.4 I can run algorithms under the General setting "Invalid features filtering" -> "Ignore features with invalid geometries" 
However, when I try Processing through Python functions like the qgis:fieldcalculator it just breaks.
Is there a way to make my QGIS python interpreter recognize that I do not care for invalid geometries?

Here is an example of a working code with valid geometries which breaks when invalid :

```
import os
import sys
import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()

from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "OSGeo4W64", "apps", "qgis"), True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

sys.path.append(os.path.join("C:", os.sep, "OSGeo4W64", "apps", "qgis", "python", "plugins"))
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Processing.initialize()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())


def add_area(input_vector):
    out = "pathtooutput.shp"
    params = {
                'INPUT': input_vector,
                'FIELD_NAME': 'area',
                'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
                'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
                'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
                'NEW_FIELD': True,
                'FORMULA': ' $area ',
                'OUTPUT': out
                }
    res = processing.run("qgis:fieldcalculator", params)
    print(res)
    return out

inp = "path_to_testvector_with_invalid_or_valid_geometries_for_test.shp"

add_area(inp)
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you've tried?

Comment: It is not necessary, I try the same at QGIS with the "Invalid features filtering" -> "Ignore features with invalid geometries"  and it works. I try "Invalid features filtering" -> "Stop algorithm execution when a geometry is invalid" and it finds invalid geometries, thus it stops.I know I have invalid geometries, so Python breaks QGIS Processing when it finds them, while when removed through side ways, it outputs properly.

Comment: The question is not a matter of code, but if in this python framework of QGIS there is an option that could be set somewhere

Comment: There is, but we'd need to see your current code to post the solution.

Comment: There you go, hope it helps a solution and anyone trying python with qgis

Comment: Since using the interface is working, try comparing your code to the code used by the interface to run the algorithm, you can find it under processing -> history

Comment: Thanks, I have done that, it is the same, no option there

Comment: @ndawson "There is, but we'd need to see your current code to post the solution"
Would you be so kind to do so after me posting my code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try changing the part:

```
params = {
            'INPUT': input_vector,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'area',
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'FORMULA': ' $area ',
            'OUTPUT': out
            }
res = processing.run("qgis:fieldcalculator", params)
```

to

```
params = {
            'INPUT': input_vector,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'area',
            'FIELD_TYPE': 0,
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 3,
            'NEW_FIELD': True,
            'FORMULA': ' $area ',
            'OUTPUT': out
            }
context = dataobjects.createContext()
context.setInvalidGeometryCheck(QgsFeatureRequest.GeometryNoCheck)
res = processing.run("qgis:fieldcalculator", params, context=context)
```

You'll also need to add these imports:

```
from processing.tools import dataobjects
from qgis.core import QgsFeatureRequest
```

Comment: It also needs the addition of "from qgis.core import QgsFeatureRequest", for the completeness of the answer

Comment: Apart from that, it works like a charm. Even adds the area. Attention to "context" param in processing call. Thanks a lot @ndawson

Comment: I have a similar problem to above, where I encounter this error:

GEOS exception: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 1528924.0830000006 485361.14200000092 0 at 1528924.0830000006 485361.14200000092 0

Is there a different .setInvalidGeometryCheck option that would; help me here? I've tried the above but the native:intersection still fails.