# PyQGIS - how to set processing to avoid bad geometry?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am getting "feature(182) has invalid geometry" . Fixing it takes a lot of time. How do I set it to ignore bad features and keep running with Python?

```
    processing.runAndLoadResults(
        "qgis:selectbylocation", parameters
    )
```

Comment: Try this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307393/qgis-python-ignore-invalid-geometries

Comment: @cm1 that's what i did, and it taking too much time. Trying to find another way